# Oracle 9i: Lock table from clearing table data

Tags: oracle9i

I was wondering if there's a concept in oracle like locking database table from clearing it's contents or deleting the table itself.

Is there a way?

please excuse me if this`s not a proper question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To stop the table owner, or other database users? Others can only do what you let them, so if they aren't given delete/ truncate privs or drop any table privs they won't be able to do those things anyway. If you're worried about the owner then you could add triggers to block things, but the owner could drop or disable those first. Not really clear what problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Alex: Thanks for the reply. I just dont want anyone to modify the table unless they are given permissions to do so. I need to reserve just one table from editting it.

Answer (score 0):

You can lock table like this way:

```
LOCK TABLE employees
   IN EXCLUSIVE MODE 
   NOWAIT;
```

EXCLUSIVE permits queries on the locked table but prohibits any other activity on it.